# Paypal express checkout without shipping address using rest api

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

Can anyone tell me how to hide the shipping address in the checkout prozess using REST Api.
All examples i found are quite old and use the classic API.

To create my payment i follow the example here from Github:

http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

No shipping address is specified in the request, but one is shown in the checkout window from paypal.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create

Comment: Please read this carefully https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create

Comment: @TejasMehta - there is no information on how to disable shipping address. I am using the REST api which contains the `amount`, `item_list` and `description` in my transaction. But how do i disable the shipping address? It does not make sense to have shipping if you are selling a virtual product / service.

Comment: if you are using REST API then use https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library this library, it is array based and it will work without setting value to shipping address.